# How to prove $(p-r+1)!\equiv-1(\mod p)$？

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if $p\in\mathbb P,r\in\mathbb N^*$and$r<p$, $(-1)^r r!\equiv-1(\mod p)$,show that $(p-r+1)!\equiv-1(\mod p)$.

My answer：Let's say $p$ is an odd prime,then

$$-1\equiv(p-1)!=r!(r+1)\cdots(p-1)\equiv(-1)^{p-r-1}r!(p-r-1)!\\
   \equiv-(p-r-1)!\equiv(\mod p)
$$
so $$(p-r+1)!\equiv(p-r)(p-r+1)!\equiv r(r-1)(\mod p)$$
We just have to prove $r(r-1)\equiv-1(\mod p)$.
What to do next？

Comment: What if $r=1$? $p!\equiv -1\pmod p$ is false.

Comment: Specialize the WIlson reflection formula in the linked dupe.

Comment: Thank you! I think the question is wrong! Should change it to $(p-r-1)!\equiv 1(\mod p)$